# Is it possible to implement method with signature List<Class<? extends Annotation>> in Java?

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

The problem is in a generic restriction:

```
public List<Class<? extends Annotation>> getAnnotations() {
    return new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(Override.class));
}
```

Real return type is `ArrayList<Class<Override>>`
Method expects `List<Class<? extends Annotation>>`

`Class<Override>` is a subtype of `Class<? extends Annotation>`
`Class<? extends Annotation> c = Override.class;` //allowed

`ArrayList` is a subtype of a `List`, if types of the elements match:
`List<? extends Number> l = new ArrayList<Integer>();` // allowed

However, this is not allowed:

```
List<Class<? extends Annotation>> l = Arrays.asList(Override.class);
List<Class<? extends Annotation>> l = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(Override.class));
```

Is it even possible or `Class` wildcards are broken?

Comment: @kocko what java did you use? I have jdk1.7_079, here's a screenshot https://www.dropbox.com/s/p6gybp1jct19ehg/generics.jpg

Comment: I played a bit with this and I think I found the reason. I will write an answer after a while.

Comment: From testing, looks like in Java 7 you need to parameterize the static call `Arrays.<Class<? extends Annotation>>asList(Override.class);`. With Java 8 I didn't need to

Comment: Exactly, I mentioned this in the answer.

Comment: this should work in java7 - `List<Class<? extends Annotation>> l = Arrays.asList(Override.class);`

Comment: this should work in java7 - `return Arrays.asList(Override.class);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would assume that this is because of the jdk 1.7 type inference nature.

As you may already know, the `Arrays.asList(T ... elems)` method is generic, but we seldom explicitly specify the type-parameter which we'd like the method to work with and thus we *rely* on the type inference feature of the compiler.

So, when the compiler *sees* an `Arrays.asList(Override.class)` statement it will **infer** that the type-parameter for the method should be replaced with `Class<Override>`, i.e. we'd have a *version* of the method in this form:

```
public List<Class<Override>> asList(Class<Override> ... elems)
```

However, if you **explicitly set** the type parameter for the method to

```
List<Class<? extends Annotation>> l = 
               Arrays.<Class<? extends Annotation>>asList(Override.class);
```

then the compiler will actually know what the type-parameter has to be replaced with and then the **version** of the `.asList()` method would be:

```
public List<? extends Annotation> asList(Class<? extends Annotation> ... elems)
```

Now this will compile fine, since `Class<? extends Annotation>` is compatible to `Class<Override>`. In Java8, the type inference feature is improved even more, so that you don't have to explicitly set the type-parameter for the `.asList()` method.

However, the **more** interesting question goes to

> Why `List<Class<Override>>` is not compatible with `List<Class<? extends Annotation>>`?

The [`java.lang.Class`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) is a `final` one, which would help answering the following two questions, the combination of which will answer the above question. :)

So,

- What does a `List<Class<Override>>` mean?

`List<Class<Override>>` means that we can add only instances of `Class<Override>` and nothing else to the list. Which is great, knowing that we can't even add `Class<Override>` sub-classes, since the `Class` type is `final`.

- What does a `List<Class<? extends Annotation>>` mean?

This type of `List` represents a whole **family** of lists of classes, all of which are subclasses of the `Annotation` type, which means that we can successfully add any annotation type (for example, `SuppressWarnings.class`, `Override.class`, `Documented.class`, etc.) to the list.

Lets assume that the following example was actually correct:

```
List<Class<Override>> overrides = Arrays.asList(Override.class);
List<Class<? extends Annotation>> annotations = new ArrayList<>();
annotations = overrides;
annotations.add(SuppressWarnings.class); //HUGE PROBLEM
annotations.add(Documented.class); //ANOTHER HUGE PROBLEM
```

The two huge problems come from the fact that we're trying to add some non-`Override` instances to the `overrides`, which is very wrong.

We have smart enough compiler that can actually detect such possible problems and throwing a compile-time error is the way to prevent us from doing this.

More info:

- [What do multi-level wildcards mean?](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeArguments.html#FAQ104)
- [Is `List<Dog>` a subclass of `List<Animal>`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p)

Comment: thanks for the time you spent. the first part tells that we just got tricked with type detection. as far as I know, there is a change in Java8, that analyses left part of assign statement, so it solves this issue. the second part refers to a classic subtyping problem in collections, i'm familiar with that. let's wait a few days to see if we missed something here, and if everything is OK, i'll accept this. thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

> ArrayList is a subtype of a List, if types of the elements match:
>
> ```
> List<? extends Number> l = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // allowed
> ```

Yes, but in your example the element types do not match:

```
List<Class<? extends Annotation>> l = new ArrayList<Class<Override>>();
```

Granted, `Class<Override>` is a subtype of `Class<? extends Annotation>`, but just like `List<String>` is not a subtype of `List<Object>`, `List<Class<Override>>` is not a subtype of `List<Class<? extends Annotation>>`. It would be a subtype of `List<? extends Class<? extends Annotation>>`, though.

That said, the reason your code does not compile is that in Java 7, type inference does not take into account the method's return type when inferring the type of a return statement's expression, so it defaults to the most specific type that could be assigned to

```
Arrays.asList(Override.class)
```

not realizing that the return statement would only compile with a more flexible type (Java 8 type inference is smarter, btw). One workaround is to explicity specify the type argument:

```
Arrays.<Class<? extends Annotation>(Override.class);
```

or give Java 7's type inference a hint by assigning to a local variable first:

```
List<Class<? extends Annotation>> list = Arrays.asList(Override.class);
return list;
```

or change the method return type to

```
List<? extends Class<? extends Annotation>> getAnnotations()
```

so the inferred type does not matter.